# How do I untar a subdirectory into the current directory?

Tags: unix, command-line, tar

How to I extract a subdirectory in a tarball into the current directory?

Example, the tarball from [wordpress](http://wordpress.org/download/):

```
wordpress/
wordpress/wp-trackback.php
wordpress/wp-config-sample.php
wordpress/wp-settings.php
wordpress/wp-rss2.php
wordpress/readme.html
wordpress/index.php
...
```

How do I extract everything under `wordpress/` into the current directory?  In otherwords, it will not create a `wordpress` directory.

I've tried this with no luck:

```
tar xvfz latest.tar.gz wordpress -C ./
```

I know I can extract it normally and move it back, but I figure there has to be a way to do it in one shot.

Comment: To those -1ing and suggesting closing this question: how come?

Comment: I have had this exact problem come up in a programming context. Let's try to be a bit more broadminded, people -- if s/wordpress/kernel_source/g is enough to make a question "programming related", it was "programming related" to begin with.

Comment: @j_random_hacker - the question is not programming related. the question is basically "how do I use the tar utility on a unix system?" there is nothing programming related about that. it might go on serverfault or on a forum for using unix.

Comment: There is no better place than here to ask such a question.  If this place excludes "non-programming" questions, the scope of the website needs to be broadened to include questions such as mine.  

Plus, there are many similar questions about tar that were not closed on these grounds (I checked before posting this).  If you are gonna close this, you should close those as well.  Or should I slightly reword this question to ask "how do I extract $RANDOM_LIBRARY" into the current directory" so it sounds like it is programming related, but really me cheating the system?

Comment: The guy's even trying to untar his php files, for pete's sake.  This site isn't just about programming, it's about knowing how to use the tools that enable it.  That's why we have rich sections on vim and emacs.  Tar is one of those tools, and passing command line arguments is just a simple scripting language.

Comment: I mean, look over at the related stuff... there are a ton of "non-programming" questions that were not closed.  Why single this out...  I searched far and wide for an answer to this question before asking here.  I mean--how is this +5 one programming related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223656/untar-ungz-gz-tar-how-do-you-remember-all-the-useful-options

Comment: @Jason: Thanks for responding. I see the value in not letting SO become "diluted" with non-programming stuff, but I think an awful lot of valid questions on here are about indirectly related things. If we cut out anything that could possibly be of value to a non-programmer, a lot of high-quality content would be lost, don't you think?

Comment: @Cory - if I saw those, I would have voted to close them. Extracting files from an archive into the current directory is not programming related, unless you're asking about an issue *writing* a tool that extracts files into the current directory. Your question is re: how to use the *basic* tools on a unix system. As such, it belongs in a forum about *using* the basic tools on a unix system. It's nothing against you or your question. It's just not programming related no matter what directory you want to extract to or what is in the archive.

Comment: @rampion - This site is just about programming, read the faq. It's also community based and many of the things with vi and emacs are programming vi and emacs to do specific things, or about programming tools like compilers and interpreters and such. As a community site, however, people may very well choose that this *is* programming related, even tho they'd be extremely hard pressed to make a true, logical case for why it were (except that the word php exists in the question somewhere... come on!)

Comment: @Jason: I think you can still vote to close those other questions (I don't think there's a time limit).

Comment: @j_random_hacker - I think that is true in part, but there are some basics that are really a stretch, and IMHO, this is one of them. I don't know that anyone could convince me that known how to use tar to extract files in the current directory and strip the first path component of the archive was programming related and not related to administration.

Comment: @j_random_hacker - I could but I don't go searching out questions just to close them. I read this question and felt that it was more appropriate for serverfault or a basic unix tools forum, so I voted to close it.

Comment: @j_random_hacker - btw, changing the question from wordpress to my_prog just obfuscates his question, it certainly doesn't make the question more programming related. It's still about "how do I use tar to do administrative stuff". I rolled back to his original second revision.

Comment: @Jason: I did check the faq, and this qualifies as "of interest to at least one other programmer somewhere".  tar is a programming tool, and like I said before, knowing how to invoke it is a type of programming.  Just as much as knowing how to invoke API calls.

Comment: @Jason: Sure, my search-and-replace did not change any material properties of the question, I was trying to make a point. Given that it makes no difference to the question, if you feel strongly enough to roll my change back, then I think it's a little inconsistent of you not to vote to close the link provided in Cory's comment. (Not suggesting you actively search for them yourself, just the +5 question with 12 answers that Cory mentioned.)

Comment: The close police is going way over its head lately.

Comment: @rampion - tar is an archive tool and tar files are a useful & popular way of moving collections of files around the internet, nothing more.
@j_random_hacker - your edits were factious, so i rolled them back--IMHO they didn't make any point. i looked at that link, it's from October. Had I seen it then, I probably would have voted to close it. I can't see any point in closing it now--it would just resurrect a pointless post (again, IMHO).

Comment: Jason, I respect your dedication, but you risk turning this place into a wikipedia.  Wikipedia is a cesspool of power-tripping admins with too much time on their hands.  I dont think you fall into that category, but care is needed to avoid having this place fall into their trap.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Why don't you untar normally, then just:

```
mv wordpress/.* .
mv wordpress/* .
rmdir wordpress
```

But alas, there's:

```
tar --strip-components=1 -zxvf wordpress.tgz
```

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to do it in one command.

Comment: Interestingly, strip components is an option for my FreeBSD boxen, but not for some of my older linux installs.

Comment: +1. Note that, if the tarfile contains a file or directory named wordpress/wordpress, your second mv command will fail. (But kudos for catching the hidden file case.)

Comment: I like --strip-components=1, very nice!

Comment: The first command won't work - `mv` will try to move `wordpress/.` and `wordpress/..` to `.`, which will fail.

Comment: On my flavor of `tar` (CentOS 6.3) `--strip-components` needs to be specified *after* the other arguments. Very useful option, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: --strip-components=1 does the job but I don't think it's very nice.  a shorter name or a single-letter option would be better, but there probably aren't many left :-)

Answer (score 6):

Surprisingly, my `tar` (GNU tar v1.16) doesn't have an option to strip initial pathname elements.

However, it seems that more recent versions sport a `--strip-components=number` parameter, which will strip that many compononents from the start of the path.

If like me you are using an older `tar`, and you are certain that the archive does not contain a directory or file named `wordpress/wordpress`, you could always just make a symlink from `wordpress` to `.`, then extract as usual:

```
ln -s . wordpress
tar xvfz latest.tar.gz wordpress
rm wordpress
```

Comment: The box I'm on doesn't have that "strip-components" param, so the symlink idea is an interesting one.  I can't help but to wonder if there is something we are missing though.  Unix is like that... there is usually some non-obvious way that you can only learn by asking.  Hence my question!

Comment: @Cory: Well I think the answer to that is "The tar developers realised, and introduced the --strip-components option." :)